# Why would swift uiview not be connected to view controller?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, iboutlet

So this is a little bit of a weird question and I am not even sure what information to provide. I have a custom view controller and UIview that is embedded in the view controller. I created an outlet for the UIView in the view controller that is connected. Everything is looking good, but when i run my program, the viewcontroller and uiview are connecting, but the uiview is not becoming a property of the view controller. (As if it's being initiated some where else in the code) This creates an exception because when i go to set the delegate, the view is seen as nil. Here is a picture of what I am looking at:

[image]

So based on how I set up the outlet, the view object should be linked to the view controller via the calendarview property.

Here is what the exception looks like as requested:

[image]

Any ideas on how i can further debug this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This has happened to me several times. Doing a clean build and deleting the derived data directory usually helps.

Comment: What does the code look like around where the crashing function is called? Specifically, how does it get a reference to the ViewController?

Comment: It's the same piece of code in the first picture. The second picture was just a smaller picture of the same code.  Does that make sense or help?

Comment: No.  I asked about what was calling the function you posted.

Comment: There is no specific call for that function. I believe it is getting called from the progression through the view controller class. I am still pretty new to swifts I forgive me if that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the `CalendarView` outlet is getting connected and initialized *before* the `dayLabel`. During its initialization, (I'm inferring) it is calling its delegate right away, and encounters the uninitialized `dayLabel`. Remember, initialization is a sequence that happens over time; the outlets do not initialize together instantaneously.

The key thing to realize is that the outlets are only guaranteed to be fully connected by the time `viewDidLoad()` is called, not before. So put a debug print in that method and the error-causing method and see which is really happening first. I know where to bet my money.

Also put `didSet { print("Hey I got initialized!") }` property observers on your `@IBOutlets` to monitor the precise timing of that as well. This forces the startup code to tell you what it's doing when.

I don't know your full UI flow; you should paste the entire codebase somewhere. But it might be correct to do:

```
if let dayLbl = dayLabel {
    dayLbl.text = date.stringWithDateOnly()
}
```

instead of assuming it's ready.